# How to implement priority queue using Sorted Linked List?

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue, linked-list

i want to implement this in c#, i have my linked list class ready, but problem occurs when i sort the class using this Sort method. How can I give priority to elements, so that the highest priority element dequeue first.

```
        public void Sort()
   {
       ListNode current=first;
       int temp;

       for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
       {
           while (current.Next != null)
           {

               if (current.Data > current.Next.Data)
               {
                   temp = current.Data;
                   current.Data = current.Next.Data;
                   current.Next.Data = current.Data;
               }
               current = current.Next;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: You said that a problem occurs; are you going to tell us what the problem is? A linked list isn't an appropriate data structure for a priority queue in the first place. Use a heap.

Comment: the problem is that this sort method is not working well, the second last & last elements in the list didn't sort.

Comment: OK, can you give us an *example* of a list that doesn't sort right? Also, what is the value of "counter"?

Comment: 6,5,4,3,2,1 after sort 1,2,3,4,5,5 & counter=6

Comment: OK, so step through the code in the debugger, and watch every step of the way. There will be a 6 in the list until at some point, there is no more 6 and there are two 5's. **That's probably where the bug is.**

Comment: i know this thing already, anyway thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to sort the list like this, just create an insert routine that inserts any new elements in the right spot and your list will always be sorted.

Rgds GJ

Comment: In the routine that inserts a new element, you say while (current.next != null && new.data > current.data) current = current.next. So you skip along the list to the right point, after that you insert the new element between current and current.next. that way your list will always be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

To analyze your code a little:

This looks like 1 stroke of a bubble-sort, so don't expect it to sort everything.

It will only ensure that the *largest* value becomes the *last* element. And only after you fix the swap part:

```
if (current.Data > current.Next.Data)
{
  temp = current.Data;
  current.Data = current.Next.Data;
  current.Next.Data = temp;
}
```